# How to get data from the row selected in a gridview with radiobutton onclicked event?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, radio-button

I've a gridview in which a radiobutton is used to select a particular row of data. The radiobutton onclick event is done through Javascript.

Now I need to save the data in this selected row into some session value so that I can use in another page. How do I achieve this?

I'm not using JQuery or Ajax, my entire coding is done on ASP.NET 3.5

Answer (score 0):

```
Session ( 'VariableHere' ) = 'Data';
// display variable anywhere on your site 
Out ( 'Your variable is ' + Session ( 'VariableHere' ) );
```

i don't understand why you would need it in session, the session is per user, you could use Application variables as I don't think you need it per session.

Answer (score 0):

The blog post [HERE](http://blog.digitaltools.com/post/2009/08/05/Select-One-Row-From-a-GridView.aspx) has the code for this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add data keys to your GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ItemID" ... >
```

Add a value to your radio button (intellisense doesn't support it, but it's there):

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" onclick="radioClick(this);" Value='<%#Container.ItemIndex%>' />
```

In your JavaScript method:

```
radioClick = function(radioCtrl){
    __doPostBack("<%=GridView1.UniqueID%>", radioCtrl.value);
}
```

And add the RaisePostBackEvent method to your code behind:

```
protected override void RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler source, string eventArgument)
{
    //call the RaisePostBack event 
    base.RaisePostBackEvent(source, eventArgument);

    if (source is GridView)
    {
        if (source == GridView1)
        {           
            int itemID = (int)GridView1.DataKeys[Int32.Parse(eventArgument)]["ItemID"];           
        }
    }
}
```